# Open Babel Warning in PerceiveBondOrders

Tags: python, protein-database, sdf, openbabel

I try to gnina docking tool for protein-ligand docking

But I can get output file just included ligand.
(there is no protein in pdb)

Is there problem at openbabel in gnina?
Or at input file format?

Command is

```
gnina -r 6vl4/6vl4.pdb -l ligand/structure.sdf --autobox_ligand 6vl4/6vl4_B_QY1.sdf --device 0 --minimize_single_full --pose_sort_order CNNaffinity -o ../gnina_output/6vl4_structure_docked.pdb --seed 0
```

The Error

```
*** Open Babel Warning  in PerceiveBondOrders
  Failed to kekulize aromatic bonds in OBMol::PerceiveBondOrders
```

[image]

[Env]
Ubuntu 18.04
python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, the output file of gnina just show the orientation of the ligands. However, you just need to open your receptor original file (-r file)  and the output file (-o file) together in a visualiser to see the ligand in the pocket of the receptor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).